# WPF effect differences

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running the same application on two different PCs, both computers are relatively new.

One of the PCs displays the controls with effects and the other displays it very primitively.

The difference is shown below:

PC1:

[image: PC1]

PC2:

[image: PC2]

Any clue why?

When building the program I get this warning:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL"

But I don't think that this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Does PC2 have its Aero themes turned off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem : the display depends on the display configuration of the computer which runs the programs.

Example : on my laptop, I use all the effects from windows 7 (in advanced configuration, you enable everything), and on my desktop, I uncheck all of them, for better performances.

The results will greatly be differents between the two pcs.
(one look like an old windows 98 and it affect what it can display)